# "Reverse for 'page' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried" in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I started testing and studying Django recently and I'm building some projects to learn and test it.
I tried looking for answers in the documentation but was unable to find any, if you can send me the documentation reference to solve this with your solution/tip, I'd appreciate it.

I'm trying to pass an argument through the URL in Django, the url changes and the int appears on the browser when redirecting (i.e. *http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit-contact/1* - 1 being put dinamically from the "redirecting") but, apparently, the view function can't recognize it.

button I'm using to redirect and send the argument

```
<a href="{% url 'edit-contact' contato.id%}" class="btn btn-primary">
  Edit contact
</a>
```

urls.py file:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('busca/', views.search, name='busca'),
    path('<int:contato_id>', views.details, name='detalhes'),
    path('edit-contact/<int:contato_id>',
         views.edit_contact, name='edit-contact'),

]
```

view function I'm using to capture the request

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='login')
def edit_contact(request, contato_id):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = ContatoForm()

        return render(request, 'contatos/detalhes.html', {'form': form, 'contato_id': contato_id})
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit-contact/1

Django Version: 3.2.9
Python Version: 3.10.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'contatos.apps.ContatosConfig',
 'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template D:\Gabriel\Codando\studying\django_learning\DjangoProj_agenda\templates\base.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'edit-contact' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit\\-contact/(?P<contato_id>[0-9]+)$']
   1 : {% load static%}
   2 : 
   3 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   4 : <html lang="pt">
   5 :   <head>
   6 :     {% include 'partials/_head.html' %}
   7 : 
   8 :     <title>{% block 'title' %}{% endblock %}</title>
   9 :   </head>
   10 : 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\gabriel\codando\studying\django_learning\DjangoProj_agenda\contatos\views.py", line 76, in edit_contact
    return render(request, 'contatos/detalhes.html', {'form': form, 'contato_id': contato_id})
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CARVALHO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /edit-contact/1
Exception Value: Reverse for 'edit-contact' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit\\-contact/(?P<contato_id>[0-9]+)$']
```

Comment: does it work if you put a space before the `%` in `contato.id%}` (in the template)?

Comment: That was my first try, it doesn't work

Comment: The problem is in your template. It seems that `contato.id` has no value assigned. That's why django does not find an url pattern for `edit-contact` without an integer. Make sure to provide a value when generating the edit-contact url.

Comment: But when it redirects, the url gets the integer as in *http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit-contact/1*, I haven't put that 1 there, it gets from the template. That's my doubt, the integer is being recognized, but not by the function

Comment: You pass it via `contato_id` to the template. But in the template you try to access with `contato.id`.

Comment: was just about to say the same as @Marco - it's a typo. Sorry I didn't spot this before. The template should have `contato_id`

Comment: But contato.id is getting the id from the contato object I instaciated. Sorry If I didn't understand you guys, if so and you can try to explain with a little more detail I'd appreciate it. :)

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can't really tell if this is a solution or just a workaround, but I did something and now it works, apparently. At least I'm not getting the error message anymore. Here's what I did.

I added a urlpattern for when edit-contact didn't have an argument, because that's what the error is talking about, or at least is what I understood from it.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('busca/', views.search, name='busca'),
    path('<int:contato_id>', views.details, name='detalhes'),
    path('edit-contact/', views.edit_contact, name='edit-contact'),
    path('edit-contact/<int:contact_id>',
         views.edit_contact, name='edit-contact'),
]
```

I came up with this solution after reading a lot of posts here in SO, reading the docs for Django and thinking alone. If anyone thinks I'm wrong or has a better solution, I'm open to suggestions, after all *I have just started learning Django*.